# Is there a project that uses two different token burning methods at the same time?

Tags: token, solidity

I'm wondering if it is positive or negative to use the "token burning function" (this decreases  the total supply) AND sending tokens to the burning address (this decreases the circulating supply)?

Does a project that uses both methods exist?

I have did quite a research, but haven't find anything meaningful so far.

Answer (score 1):

Sending tokens to an unused address, like the address zero, is a method to burn tokens when the smart contract does not implement a token-burning mechanism. You can throw tokens away and consider them burned. But of course, decreasing the total supply would be cleaner than throwing tokens away like this, instead. So if you are developing the contract, I recommend you implement a burning mechanism that decreases total supply. This way you can track how many tokens are out there, easily.